# drawing lines from a list in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, draw, lines

I'm using a list of pixels to draw lines from using pygame.
I use the pygame.time.get_ticks() function to add new pixels to the list every second in order to have multiple lines drawing simultaneously as the program advances.
Here's a snippet from the code:

```
    screen_size = [self.xsize, self.ysize]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
    start_points = list()
    start_points.append(self.get_random_pixel())
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    while True

        if time.time.get_ticks() % 1000 == 0:
            start_points.append(self.get_random_pixel())

        for i in range(len(start_points)):
            old_coord = start_points[i]
            new_coord = self.nearest_neighbor(old_coord)
            pygame.draw.line(screen, self.get_col(old_coord), old_coord, new_coord, 2)
            start_points[i] = new_coord
            pygame.display.flip()
```

Some notions on that:
1. I only get one line drawing when I run this.
2. the list start_points does seem to be growing with more pixels added to it as the program advances.
3. When the list is of a fixed size (let's say 100) I do have 100 lines drawing simultaneously.

So what's going on here? why don't I have more lines drawing simultaneously as time passes?

Thanks!
omer

Comment: This can't be your actual code, because there's at least one `SyntaxError`. Also, it's not _complete_ code. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is much easier to help with, because people can run it to see what it does instead of trying to understand your description, debug it, play with it, etc.

Comment: Pygame has a built in get_ticks function [pygame.time.get_ticks()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks%20pygame.time.get_ticks%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try to use SSCCE from now on.

Comment: @monkey: I assume that's what he's already using, because the stdlib `time` module doesn't have a `time` type, or a `get_ticks()` function or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens if your loop takes, say, 23 milliseconds to run. So, the first time you call `get_ticks`, you get 0. Then you get 23, 46, …, 989, 1012, …, 1978, 2001, …, 2990, 3013, …, and so on. It'll be 23 seconds before you hit the first number divisible by 1000!

Of course in real life, your loop time isn't constant, but highly variable, but you have basically the same problem.

The right way to solve this is to reorganize your program around either an event loop, or a fixed frame-rate loop.

With an event loop, you can just use [`set_timer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to fire an event once/second. Also, instead of redrawing and flipping the screen as fast as possible even when nothing is happening, burning up 100% CPU constantly and maybe even making your game sluggish to respond to events, you'll only redraw and flip the screen when it's actually necessary, using almost no CPU and almost always being ready to respond.

With a fixed frame rate of, say, 20fps, you can just fire every 20th frame. And again, you'll only be redrawing the screen 20 times/second instead of as fast as possible, so you'll have much less CPU usage, and can respond to anything in 1/20th of a second.

But if you really want to do it this way, you can. You just have to keep track of the next time to fire. For example:

```
next_line_time = 0

while True:

    while time.time.get_ticks() >= next_line_time:
        start_points.append(self.get_random_pixel())
        next_line_time += 1000
```

---

As a side note, you almost never want a loop over `range(len(foo))` in Python. Just loop over `foo`; then you don't need all those `foo[i]` in the loop. If you really do need the index as well as the value, you can always loop over `enumerate(foo)`, which gives you both. For example:

```
for i, old_coord in enumerate(start_points):
    new_coord = self.nearest_neighbor(old_coord)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, self.get_col(old_coord), old_coord, new_coord, 2)
    start_points[i] = new_coord
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Also, you almost certainly don't want to call `flip` after each line. It should take microseconds to draw each line, and trying to flip any faster than your monitor and/or your eyes can detect is a waste.